# Java Protobuff java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am using the protobuff 2.5.0 in my project and when i try to use the protofbuff generated java classes, i am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.test.PersonModel$Person overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
```

Comment: are you sure you're using *both* the code-gen (`protoc`) tool (and the code it generates) **and** the library code *for the same version*? Meaning: if you're using protoc 2.5.0, you need to use the jar files from 2.5.0

Comment: Yes that was the issue. The consumer of protobuf was expecting 2.4.0 ,  but the actual classes were generated out of 2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue due to incompatibility between the different protobuf versions (2.4.0 and 2.5.0). The consumer of protobuf was expecting 2.4.0 , but the actual classes were generated out of protobuf 2.5.0. After regenerating the java classes using protobuf 2.4.0 resolved the issue.