# Google Protobuf VerifyError

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protobuf version 2.6.1 and wanted to use the option

`option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;`

I am getting the following exception as soon as I do so.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.pbo.common.network.message.NetworkProtocol$NetworkMessage$HpSyncMessage overrides final method com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.isInitialized()Z`

As soon as I remove the lite runtime option, the error goes away. Not sure what's causing this. I tried cleaning gradle caches etc to see if that helps but to no avail.

Comment: Please share your codebase to resolve the problem.

Comment: May be a duplicate of this 2 year old issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245488/java-protobuff-java-lang-verifyerror

Though there is no flagged answer, one of the comments on the question seems to indicate a resolution was found. Check if you also have a desynch in compilation.

Comment: This means that the instrumentation process is implementing the isInitialized method within the subclass but alas that method is a final method.  Therefore you can't implement that method within any subclass.  Does the com.pbo.common.network.message.NetworkProtocol$NetworkMessage$HpSyncMessage class reference and/or implement the IsInitialized method?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you provide an example we can run

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi yes it is implementing that method. I tested with a small example and it always adds isInitialized method.

Comment: @Raniz I cannot because the proto file generates a 20mb plus java file.

Comment: Can you minimise it to something that presents the issue without extra fluff? That's usually a good debugging exercise as well

Comment: Is that class something that was generated by the protobuf library or is it something that you created?  if it is something you created then can you rename that method and try again?.